# jQuery post fail() callback has empty responseText

Tags: jquery, servlets

Consider jquery code

```
            var posting = $.post(
                url,
                json
            ).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An Error Occurred: "+jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            ).done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("Success: " + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            )
            ;
```

in the done() method the responseText is what I expect, but in the fail() method it is always empty string.

Servlet code is like so:

```
try {
    doSomething();
    response.getOutputStream().print("doSomething worked properly");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    response.sendError(500, e.getMessage());
    response.getOutputStream().print("doSomething failed with error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

In the fail method I'm expecting to see the jqXHR.responseText have the value from the servlet print statement, but instead it is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, rather than calling response.sendError(), which apparently "clears the buffer" [javadoc: Sends an error response to the client using the specified status and clears the buffer.] I changed it to call:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

and now it does what I expect on the javascript/jquery side.

Thanks for looking.